# How to set dynamic v-model for input and set value to this v-model in Vue 2

Tags: vue.js

I have a component for creating dynamic input fields. I have a prop - fields.

```
fields: [
            {
                label: 'Question Text',
                placeholder: 'Enter Text',
                isRequired: true,
                editable: true,
                name: 'question',
                value: '123',
            },
            {
                label: 'Button Text',
                placeholder: 'Enter Text',
                isRequired: true,
                editable: true,
                name: 'button',
                value: '',
            },
        ],
```

Than I pass this to component SettingsViewFields.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <e-form-group v-for="(field, index) in fields" :key="index" :error="getInputError[field.name]">
            <template v-slot:label>
                {{ field.label }}
            </template>
            <e-textarea
                v-model="form[field.name]"
                :name="field.name"
                size="small"
                @input="onInput($event, field.name)"
            ></e-textarea>
        </e-form-group>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'SettingsViewFields',

    props: {
        fields: {
            type: Array,
            default: () => [],
        },
    },

    data: () => ({
        form: [],
    }),
};
</script>
```

I want that reactive data for input calls from field.name that the reactive data will be form: {question: '', button: ''} But the problem I have to set correct value for input, but if I set field.name the value will be not correct because for first input it's value: '123'.

Answer (score 1):

You can't Change the data passed by the parent component directly, when you receive the prop data from parent that you want update, you can make a copy of this,eg

```
 computed: {
    fieldsCopy: function () {
      return this.fields
    },
}
```

and use fieldsCopy in your template, that may work.
if you also want to pass the updated data to parent , use [emit](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Emitting-a-Value-With-an-Event).